# RAID controller detecting SSD as foreign after every reboot

Tags: raid, hard-drive, ssd, smart

My server, an R610, has been detecting my SSD as foreign after every reboot. It has a PERC 6/i RAID controller, but there's no actual RAID stuff (I just have all the drives as their own VDs).

This had happened a few times over the last year or two, but it's been happening every single time I reboot now. The drive is a Kingston SSD (240GB, 2.5"), and the SMART status doesn't show anything odd.

I do have two other drives, neither of which are affected when this happens. Does anyone know what might be happening?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it's a) normal, and b) it's not something you can fix easily.

The reason is you're using non-Dell part with Dell controller. Anything not reporting "DELL" with the firmware as part of the m_VendorId field inside SCSIOP_INQUIRY (0x12) command response WILL NOT function properly and will definitely bring in the issues you're experiencing from time to time. The only reliable way to get rid of the behavior you're suffering from is to flash Dell firmware into your SSD or if it's not possible - replace "alien" SSD with something saying "F, I'm Dell!" to RAID/HBA.

Comment: Due to some other issues I was having, and the fact that all three of my drives were pretty inexpensive (and probably poorly made), I've just bought a pair of genuine Dell HDDs that I found on sale. Hopefully they'll work better (unfortunately I didn't consider the fact it's two days before Christmas, so they probably won't arrive for a little while).

Comment: It’s a way to go! Good luck!